# Swift 4 Change UIBarButtonItem System Icon not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UIBarButtonItems inside my Navigation Item's Right Bar Button Items. I am looking to changing the second UIBarButtonItem only programmatically.

I have created an outlet for this UIBarButtonItem:

```
@IBOutlet var downloadButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

and then I tried to change it like so:

```
self.downloadButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash, target: self, action: #selector(PlayerController.downloadButtonPressed(_:)))
```

But the UIBarButtonItem does not change over, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> But the UIBarButtonItem does not change over

There's no reason why it would. All you're doing is replacing the value of a variable `downloadButton` with a new bar button item. This has no effect on the bar button item still sitting there in the navigation bar — plus, you have destroyed your reference to that bar button item.

You have to reconfigure your `navigationItem`. You can also set your `downloadButton` again if you like, but more likely you'll realize you never needed the `downloadButton` outlet for anything in the first place.

Here's an example from one of my own apps, where I toggle the right bar button item between being a Play button and being a Pause button:

```
let whichButton : UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem? = {
    switch self.mp.currentPlaybackRate {
    case 0..<0.1:
        return .play
    case 0.1...1.0:
        return .pause
    default:
        return nil
    }
}()
if let which = whichButton {
    let bb = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: which, 
        target: self, action: #selector(doPlayPause))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bb
}
```

Notice the last line: I just reach right in and change the `navigationItem`. Instantly the navigation bar display changes to match.

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bb replaces my first button, I am looking to replace the second bar button item inside rightBarButtonItem

Comment: Correct, I'm not writing your code for you, I'm showing you the technique. You need to change your `rightBarButtonItems` array. The point is, I explained why _your_ code was not doing anything (which is what you asked), and I told you how to do something that _will_ do something.